# Winter 20 - change in behaviour - "New" button on Lookup search results

Tags: lookup, button-overrides, winter20

It seems there might have been an undocumented change to the behaviour in lookups in Winter '20?

Previously, when clicking the "New" link at the bottom of search results, I'm pretty sure that a "New" modal would pop-up, regardless of whether the "New" action had been overridden with cu

Now, it seems that the "New" link recognises the override. This would be good, except:

- The override re-directs the user to a fresh page with the custom "New" process on it. This means that the user loses any work they had done on the record they were working on.
- The custom "New" process doesn't appear to have context provided to it, so we can't adapt our "New" process to re-direct back to the record which was being created.

This change in behaviour runs the risk of being a worse user experience than before? Has anybody else seen this and worked around/with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was an intentional fix: [New button override not considered when the object is created via a lookup field in a parent object](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003d8SQAQ&title=new-button-override-not-considered-when-the-object-is-created-via-a-lookup-field-in-a-parent-object).

While I agree with your points that this is terrible UX, it does make sense to apply the override behavior to all "New" buttons.

Comment: I would report the broken UX to Salesforce - just because they corrected override behaviour doesn't mean they can't have introduced a new bug in the UX flows. Perhaps they can ensure in this context a separate tab should be opened for the override presentation, so after creation you return to the original with the lookup updated and having not lost any details.

Comment: Agreed Phil. I still consider this a bug.

Comment: You're right - I hadn't spotted the Known Issue listing, thanks! I can report the problems with the new behaviour, but don't have developer support, so this will likely be closed without any attention, unfortunately.