# Winter 20 - Custom Override Redirect Issue

Tags: lightning-aura-components, redirect, button-overrides, modal, winter20

When I create a new Account I have a lookup field to Contact with a custom aura component override for the “New” button.

The issue I’m having is that when the user is creating an Account and wants to add a new Contact it redirects to the Contact override component then redirects to the new Contact record page when saved. This loses all the data from the original Account form due to the redirect.

Is there a way to have the Contact override pop-up in its own modal so it doesn’t navigate away from the Account creation page?

Issue has been happening since Winter 20' release

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/284641/winter-20-change-in-behaviour-new-button-on-lookup-search-results

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be a Winter 20 release issue